# Set up Amazon routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have http://myapps.com site and a have some particular web applications which runs on difference amazone machines.

I need run app1 by this url  http://myapps.com/app1 and app2 by this  http://myapps.com/app2

How I need set up AWS to made this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS does not, and cannot, route HTTP requests.

Comment: Ok , what another solution ?

Comment: you might look at a reverse proxy (for instance, with nginx) to route between those. Alternately, app1 can proxy requests to app2.